# How to use mat-autocomplete & ng-model in same Input Form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

In an new Row Scenario I Want to display an Input, where we can key 3 characters and an autocomplete will hit the db and returns the all other remaining fields..

But in View mode i need to work the same input form to use ng-model..to bind the value which we already save

The code snippet is below

```
<mat-form-field class="three">
              <input matInput autofocus="true" [formControl]="mcodeSearchControl" #MaterialCode name="MaterialCode" [readonly]="!row.editing"
                [(ngModel)]="row.currentData.materialCode" required maxlength="10" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
              <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [style.display]="isNew ? 'auto': 'none'" [displayWith]="mCodeDisplay"
                (optionSelected)='selectionChanged($event, row)'>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let option of mCode$ | async" [value]="option">
                  {{option.materialCode}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-autocomplete>
            </mat-form-field>
```